# QWebEngine 5.7.1 Offline navigation loading cache

Tags: c++, qt, caching, chromium, qwebengineview

I'm trying to develop a web application using QWebEngine but I'm facing a problem while handling offline state since I'm always redirected o Chromium error page "There is no Internet connection". I read that QWebEngine uses Chromiums network stack rather than QNetworkAccessManager. 
I've got few questions regarding this system:

a) is there no way to bypass QtWebEngine network stack and use QNetworkAccess manager to store and load cache?

b) It is possible to set offline setting as in chrome using some address similar to chrome://flags/#show-saved-copy ?

c) It is possible to store last website html page and once system detect offline state redirect to a local html stored in memory?

d) There is no way to show button  "Show saved copy" in offline state in QWebEngine on qt 5.7.1?

Answer (score 0):

> [is] there no way to use bypass QtWebEngine network stack [...]?

There is. It would require linking the Chromium process with QtNetwork module, and reimplementing its networking with Qt. It's not a trivial task, but neither an insurmountable one. See [this page of the Blink Network Stack](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack) for reference, and compare with what Qt offers.